# unable to serve static html files using app.use

Tags: node.js, express

my html file is stored in public folder.when the server starts and when i go to  the browser it shows cannot GET/.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

const pathjoin = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

const port = process.env.PORT ||3000 ;

app.use(express.static(pathjoin));
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('server started');
});
```

Comment: you need to use the actual file name after `/` for example `http://localhost:3000/index.html`

Comment: still it doesnt load the html files and as per my knowledge we dont need to go to the path in url. For example even when i use : app.use('/',express.static(path.join)); it dosnt load the files

Comment: Can you share the structure within the public folder and the URL you are using to call the page?

Comment: node modules,public/index.html,server/.server.js and the url is localhost:3000

Comment: then `http://localhost:3000/index.html` will work and not `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: no. .it doesnt work! it says Cannot GET /index.html

Answer (score 0):

i solved it . i didnt sopecify the file path for html file correctly . It should be const pathjoin = path.join(__dirname , '../public'); as my file structure was public/index.html,server/server.js
Thanks everybody for the help though!